# Powershell Get-Counter not returning values for SQL counters

Tags: sql-server

This is a cross-post from dba.stackexchange.com: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64898/powershell-get-counter-not-returning-values-for-sql-counters

---

I am attempting to use PowerShell to get some SQL counters but it doesn't seem to return the SQL specific counters anymore. I am not sure what could have changed on my server that would have caused this.

The script is pretty straight-forward, I am not sure what I am missing:

```
## Define some variables
$serverName = "ISOMORPH" # Server we are collecting from

# Define our list of counters
$counters = @(
    "\Memory\Available MBytes",
    "\Memory\Pages/sec",
    "\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Avg. Disk sec/Read",
    "\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Avg. Disk sec/Write",
    "\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Current Disk Queue Length",
    "\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Read",
    "\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Write",
    "\PhysicalDisk(*)\Current Disk Queue Length",
    "\Process(sqlservr)\% Privileged Time",
    "\Process(sqlservr)\% Processor Time",
    "\Processor(*)\% Privileged Time",
    "\Processor(*)\% Processor Time",
    "\SQLServer:Buffer Manager\Buffer cache hit ratio",
    "\SQLServer:Buffer Manager\Buffer cache hit ratio base",
    "\SQLServer:Buffer Manager\Lazy writes/sec",
    "\SQLServer:Buffer Manager\Page life expectancy",
    "\SQLServer:Memory Manager\Memory Grants Pending" ,
    "\SQLServer:SQL Statistics\Batch Requests/sec",
    "\System\Context Switches/sec",
    "\System\Processor Queue Length" 
)


## Get our performance counter data
Get-Counter -Counter $counters -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 1
```

The script will return all of the counters, but all of the SQL counters show 0 values. I am not getting any errors, it just shows all of the SQL counters as having a value of 0.

If I manually open Performance Monitor I can see these counters and they have values. I am running this on a Windows 7 laptop with SQL 2014 Developer Edition installed.

Further testing leads me to believe this is an OS specific problem. Someone else tested this script with Windows 8.1 running SQL 2012 and it returns 0 for the SQL specific counters in that case as well.

Comment: Could you confirm that the Buffer cache hit ratio gives a non zero response, and the buffer cache hit ratio base gives a 0 response? When trying to reproduce your issue I noticed that several of your counters, I did not have when listing all SQL counters. (Tested on Windows server 2012 SQL 2012)

Comment: All of the above SQL counters return 0. But they are non-zero when running perfmon on the box directly.